# SBSe 2011 All users can login into the same PC on the network and access the SBS shares minus one user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-sbs-2011

All users can login into the same PC (our board room PC) on the network and access the SBSe shares minus one user who can login but cannot mount the mapped network drives or access his Desktop which is redirected to the server. The user is a member of the Administrators Group.

The user can login to all other PCs on the network and access the shared folders and their redirected desktop.

What can I do to get him access to the shares and his desktop?

Is their a cached policy or something that I can refresh or force to update that lets the PC or server know that the user has access rights?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done a `gpresult /r` to see if they are getting the necessary group memberships? Another thing you could do is rename the users profile folder and have them login and let it create a new profile folder to see if that resolves the issue.